# Arraylist with 2 constructors from subclasses

Tags: java, arraylist, subclass

I am trying to create a simple GUI with Java. I have an Arraylist 
executed like this:

```
private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new Arraylist<>();
```

Im trying to pass in a subclass object with more parameters than the superclass.

I have tried Casting it and overriding toString method but nothing seemed to work

My supeprclass:

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    private int speed; 
    public Vehicle (int speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

My subclasses:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {
    private int gear; 
    public Car (int speed, int gear) {
        super(speed);
        this.gear = gear;
    }
}

public class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public Bike (int speed) {
        super(speed);
    }
}
```

I instantiate in the class where i initialize the Arraylist

```
Car car = new Car (100, 5);
vehicles.add(car);
```

i can initialize Car without problems. Parameters get sent, but the result im getting is only an instance of the superclass. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Where is the code part with the instantiation?

Comment: If you do `Vehicle v1 = new Car(100, 5)` it's obviously just a Vehicle, but you could cast it to a car if you know it's a `Car`. If you do `Car v1 = new Car(100, 5)` it's a new object of type `Car`, no need for casting. What was the question?

Comment: remove the extra parenthesis from the class declarations

Comment: Does this code compile with the `extends ... ` **()** - I doubt it ?

Comment: I fixed my typing errors. sorry about those.

Comment: You have declared your list to hold Vehicle objects so that’s why all objects you get back from the list are typed as Vehicle but in reality they have not changed. A Car is still a Car etc. Use instanceof and type casting to get the right type back for you list objects

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i try to add an instance of Car to the arraylist but i get an instance of Vehicle when i print it out

Comment: I get that now, see my previous comment

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the complete relevant parts of the code. Instantiation? toString()? Which unexpected results where in the sources?

Comment: Have you made sure that the `Car` class has a different `toString` method than `Vehicle`, that prints both the speed and the gear?

Comment: @Abra i didn’t mention anything about generics, I just tried to write an easy to to understand explanation about using sub classes in a collection defined to hold the superclass. Don’t put words in other people’s mouths and try to relax a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a well-known aspect of *java generics* that `List<Car>` is **not** a subclass of `List<Vehicle>`. That's why there are constructs such as `List<? extends Vehicle>` and `List<? super Car>`. There are many online resources that show how to handle your situation. For example [Generics, Inheritance and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)